# Angularjs select event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, event-handling, angular-material

I have been looking for an event handler which can help me prevent rendering the drop down list of a select element based on the logic that I can plugin on this event handler. Is there any way to do this in Angularjs for select or md-select?

Answer (score 0):

Would disabling the `md-select` be the kind of thing you are looking for? - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/BLQxwk?editors=1010#0)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as vm" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout="column" layout-align="start start">
  <md-input-container id="myInputContainer">
    <label>Choose</label>
    <md-select ng-model='choice' ng-disabled="vm.disabled">
      <md-option ng-repeat='option in vm.options' value='{{option.value}}'>{{option.label}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="vm.toggle()">Toggle</md-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ngDialog'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
  this.disabled = false;

  this.options = [
    {value: 1, label: "Option 1"},
    {value: 2, label: "Option 2"},
    {value: 3, label: "Option 3"}
  ]

  this.toggle = function () {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
  }
});
```